# Dynamic store value in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a simple store, and I want to have a store value that sums up all the values in an array automatically, but I am unsure what is the best approach with mutations, methods or computed values.

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
      my_list_values: [10,9,10],
      list_sum: 29
    }
}
```

I would like for the list_sum value to function that sums up my_list_values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `getter` which holds your logic for `listSum` and can be used in components

```js
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
      my_list_values: [10,9,10],
    }
    getters: {
      listSum (state) {
        //logic to sum values
      }
  }
}
```

You can use this getter anywhere in your components as below

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

 computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'listSum',
      // ...
    ])
  }
```

OR

```js
this.$store.getters.listSum
```

For Ref : [Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)